# Unknown USB device not responding to setup address, significantly slows boot speed

Tags: boot, 16.04, usb, dmesg

When booting into Ubuntu 16.04 (even with no USB devices plugged in) I get confronted with the following:

```
[    1.931104] usb 3-7: new low-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[    7.043191] usb 3-7: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[   17.259287] usb 3-7: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[   17.475280] usb 3-7: new low-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[   22.587338] usb 3-7: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[   32.803433] usb 3-7: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[   33.019425] usb 3-7: new low-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[   33.020984] usb 3-7: Device not responding to setup address.
[   33.224987] usb 3-7: Device not responding to setup address.
[   33.427426] usb 3-7: device not accepting address 6, error -71
[   33.539431] usb 3-7: new low-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[   33.540989] usb 3-7: Device not responding to setup address.
[   33.744991] usb 3-7: Device not responding to setup address.
[   33.947431] usb 3-7: device not accepting address 7, error -71
```

I tried booting in a Live session as well, same problem (no USB devices connected).

I have no idea where to begin to debug because this error pops up even with no USB devices connected to the computer. Here's my `lsusb` output (with some USB devices connected):

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8009 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 008: ID 1af3:0001  
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 5986:066d Acer, Inc 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0582:012f Roland Corp. QUAD-CAPTURE
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

$ lsusb -t
/:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/6p, 5000M
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/14p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 1, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 2, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 3, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 4, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 480M
    |__ Port 6: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 6: Dev 3, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 9: Dev 8, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/2p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/8p, 480M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/2p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/6p, 480M
```

Anything else I can provide for you guys?

Comment: Some usb devices are internal -- bus 3, dev 7 isn't even listed, what's not working?

Comment: @ubfan1 Everything is working.

Comment: Unplug your Roland, and maybe your webcam, and I'll be the error messages go away. Cheers, Al

Comment: @heynnema as I said in the initial post, the error persists even with no USB devices connected. The webcam is internal. I've already tried giving it zero authorization in a udev rule, that didn't help.

Comment: I got confused, as your initial post said with no USB devices connected, but the lsusb showed that there were some connected. Cheers, Al